# SonarQube throwing Malformed network data Exception getting SVN info

Tags: svn, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I've got a SonarQube 5.4 server configured as a Standalone SonarQube Anaylsis and running with Jenkins, with Jenkins integrating with our SVN server (v1.5.4) just fine. The issue occurs when I enable to SCM scanner on SonarQube the analysis fails throwing this exception in the Jenkins log.

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error when executing blame for file <XXXX>
...
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E210004: Malformed network data
```

Immeditately before this it logs some INFO's stating

```
INFO: 0/1327 files analyzed
INFO: Missing blame information for the following files:
```

Then lists a lot of the files in the project.

What's causing this issue and how do I go about fixing it? Is it as simple as needing to update SVN?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in SVNKit (https://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SVNKIT-606). Are you using the latest version of the SonarQube SVN plugin (1.3)? Since it is shipping SVNKit 1.8.11 I would expect your issue to be solved.

Comment: I have updated to the 1.3 version of the SVN plugin, I'll continue to look into the issue down this path and see if I can isolate it as n SVNKit issue specifically.